# Adding Date Picker to view programmatically?

Tags: iphone, datepicker

Can someone illustrate (or point me to a good tutorial) on how to add a Date Picker to a view programmatically (i.e., without using the interface editor)?

Answer (score 39):

It's very easy man.You can do it in seconds.

Just use the these methods in your.m file...all is ready

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,250,0,0);

    UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [myPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:)               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:myPicker];
    [myPicker release]; 
}

- (void)pickerChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"value: %@",[sender date]);
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and am not getting anything to display. Is there something else that needs to be added?

Comment: @VictorEngel Try changing this `CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,CHANGE HERE,0,0);`

Comment: Wow, this is so old I'd already forgotten about it. However, looking at the code here, I would suggest the frame has a zero size. I checked the code for a project I might have been using at the time, and I have this: `datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);`. Not sure why you'd want zero height and width unless you were hiding the view.

Answer (score 3):

Create it as you would a normal object, using UIView's `initWithFrame` method. Keep in mind that frame rectangle you specify should be created in terms of the superview's bounds. Here's an example, you'll probably need to change the frame rectangle, and add your own code to set up the date picker as needed.

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:[superview bounds]];
[superview addSubview:datePicker];
[datePicker release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the UIControls example provided in the iPhone SDK sample code. That shows you how to add almost any control programatically.

And the size of a picker is fixed. It is 320x216

Comment: It's better if you provide reference link or additional detail for iPhone SDK sample code to UIControls.